# Access element whose parent is hidden - cypress.io

Tags: javascript, angular, pug, ui-automation, cypress

The question is as given in the title, ie, to access element whose parent is hidden. The problem is that, as per the [cypress.io docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/overview/why-cypress.html)  :

> An element is considered **hidden** if:
>
> - Its width or height is 0.
> - Its CSS property (or ancestors) is visibility: hidden.
> - ***Its CSS property (or ancestors) is display: none.***
> - Its CSS property is position: fixed and it’s offscreen or covered up.

But the code that I am working with requires me to click on an element whose ***parent is hidden, while the element itself is visible***.

So each time I try to click on the element, it throws up an error reading :

> CypressError: Timed out retrying: expected
>   '< mdc-select-item#mdc-select-item-4.mdc-list-item>' to be 'visible'
>
> This element '< mdc-select-item#mdc-select-item-4.mdc-list-item>' is
>   not visible because its parent
>   '< mdc-select-menu.mdc-simple-menu.mdc-select__menu>' has CSS property:
>   'display: none'

[image]

The element I am working with is a `dropdown item`, which is written in `pug`. The element is a component defined in [angular-mdc-web](https://github.com/trimox/angular-mdc-web), which uses the `mdc-select` for the dropdown menu and `mdc-select-item` for its elements (items) which is what I have to access.

A sample code of similar structure :

```
//pug
mdc-select(placeholder="installation type"
            '[closeOnScroll]'="true")
    mdc-select-item(value="false") ITEM1
    mdc-select-item(value="true") ITEM2
```

In the above, `ITEM1` is the element I have to access. This I do in `cypress.io` as follows :

```
//cypress.io
// click on the dropdown menu to show the dropdown (items)
cy.get("mdc-select").contains("installation type").click();
// try to access ITEM1
cy.get('mdc-select-item').contains("ITEM1").should('be.visible').click();
```

Have tried with `{force:true}` to force the item click, but no luck. Have tried to select the items using `{enter}` keypress on the parent `mdc-select`, but again no luck as it throws :

> CypressError: cy.type() can only be called on textarea or :text. Your
>   subject is a: < mdc-select-label
>   class="mdc-select__selected-text">Select ...< /mdc-select-label>

Also tried using the [`select` command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/select.html#Usage), but its not possible because the Cypress engine is not able to identify the element as a `select` element (because its not, inner workings are different). It throws :

> CypressError: cy.select() can only be called on a . Your
>   subject is a: < mdc-select-label
>   class="mdc-select__selected-text">Select ...< /mdc-select-label>

The **problem** is that the `mdc-select-menu` that is the parent for the `mdc-select-item` has a property of `display:none` by some internal computations upon opening of the drop-down items.

[image]

This property is overwritten to `display:flex`, but this does not help.

[image]

All out of ideas. This works in `Selenium`, but does not with `cypress.io`. Any clue what might be a possible hack for the situation other than shifting to other frameworks, or changing the UI code?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After much nashing-of-teeth, I think I have an answer.

I think the root cause is that `mdc-select-item` has `display:flex`, which allows it to exceed the bounds of it's parents (strictly speaking, this feels like the wrong application of display flex, if I remember the tutorial correctly, however...).

Cypress does a lot of parent checking when determining visibilty, see [visibility.coffee](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/2b2b6d99a9f1bf232d9c7396b25390913d5f2b18/packages/driver/src/dom/visibility.coffee),

```
## WARNING:
## developer beware. visibility is a sink hole
## that leads to sheer madness. you should
## avoid this file before its too late.
...
when $parent = parentHasDisplayNone($el.parent())
  parentNode = $elements.stringify($parent, "short")

  "This element '#{node}' is not visible because its parent '#{parentNode}' has CSS property: 'display: none'"
...
when $parent = parentHasNoOffsetWidthOrHeightAndOverflowHidden($el.parent())
  parentNode  = $elements.stringify($parent, "short")
  width       = elOffsetWidth($parent)
  height      = elOffsetHeight($parent)

  "This element '#{node}' is not visible because its parent '#{parentNode}' has CSS property: 'overflow: hidden' and an effective width and height of: '#{width} x #{height}' pixels."
```

But, when using `.should('be.visible')`, we are stuck with parent properties failing child visibility check, even though we can actually see the child.
We need an alternate test.

### The work-around

Ref [jquery.js](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/2b2b6d99a9f1bf232d9c7396b25390913d5f2b18/packages/server/test/support/fixtures/projects/e2e/static/jquery.js), this is one definition for visibility of the element itself (ignoring parent properties).

```
jQuery.expr.pseudos.visible = function( elem ) {
  return !!( elem.offsetWidth || elem.offsetHeight || elem.getClientRects().length );
}
```

so we might use that as the basis for an alternative.

```
describe('Testing select options', function() {

  // Change this function if other criteria are required.
  const isVisible = (elem) => !!( 
    elem.offsetWidth || 
    elem.offsetHeight || 
    elem.getClientRects().length 
  )

  it('checks select option is visible', function() {

    const doc = cy.visit('http://localhost:4200')
    cy.get("mdc-select").contains("installation type").click()

    //cy.get('mdc-select-item').contains("ITEM1").should('be.visible') //this will fail
    cy.get('mdc-select-item').contains("ITEM1").then (item1 => {
      expect(isVisible(item1[0])).to.be.true
    });
  });

  it('checks select option is not visible', function() {

    const doc = cy.visit('http://localhost:4200')
    cy.get("mdc-select").contains("installation type").click()

    cy.document().then(function(document) {

      const item1 = document.querySelectorAll('mdc-select-item')[0]
      item1.style.display = 'none'

      cy.get('mdc-select-item').contains("ITEM1").then (item => {
        expect(isVisible(item[0])).to.be.false
      })
    })
  });

  it('checks select option is clickable', function() {

    const doc = cy.visit('http://localhost:4200')
    cy.get("mdc-select").contains("installation type").click()
    
    //cy.get('mdc-select-item').contains("ITEM1").click()    // this will fail
    cy.get('mdc-select-item').contains("ITEM1").then (item1 => {
    
      cy.get('mdc-select-item').contains("ITEM2").then (item2 => {
        expect(isVisible(item2[0])).to.be.true  //visible when list is first dropped
      });
          
      item1.click();
      cy.wait(500)
          
      cy.get('mdc-select-item').contains("ITEM2").then (item2 => {
        expect(isVisible(item2[0])).to.be.false  // not visible after item1 selected
      });
    });
    
  })
```

---

**Footnote - Use of 'then' (or 'each')**

The way you normally use assertion in cypress is via command chains, which basically wraps the elements being tested and handles things like retry and waiting for DOM changes.

However, in this case we have a contradiction between the standard visibility assertion `.should('be.visible')` and the framework used to build the page, so we use `then(fn)` ([ref](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/then.html)) to get access to the unwrapped DOM. We can then apply our own version of the visibility test using stand jasmine expect syntax.

It turns out you can also use a function with `.should(fn)`, this works as well

```js
it('checks select option is visible - 2', function() {
  const doc = cy.visit('http://localhost:4200')
  cy.get("mdc-select").contains("installation type").click()

  cy.get('mdc-select-item').contains("ITEM1").should(item1 => {
    expect(isVisible(item1[0])).to.be.true
  });
});
```

Using `should` instead of `then` makes no difference in the visibility test, but note the `should` version can retry the function multiple times, so it can't be used with `click` test (for example).

From the docs,

> What’s the difference between .then() and .should()/.and()?
>
> Using .then() simply allows you to use the yielded subject in a callback function and should be used when you need to manipulate some values or do some actions.
>
> When using a callback function with .should() or .and(), on the other hand, there is special logic to rerun the callback function until no assertions throw within it. You should be careful of side affects in a .should() or .and() callback function that you would not want performed multiple times.

You can also solve the problem by extending chai assertions, but the documentation for this isn't extensive, so potentially it's more work.

Comment: Thank you for all the effort put into getting a work-around. It works. The simple usage of `then` with Arrow function to access the element does the trick (though it still is invisible according to Cypress). Could you if possible clarify a bit more to the weird workings there and why when only using the `then` it is that it works?

Answer (score 4):

For convenience and reusability I had to mix the answer of Richard Matsen and Josef Biehler.

#### Define the command

```
// Access element whose parent is hidden
Cypress.Commands.add('isVisible', {
  prevSubject: true
}, (subject) => {
  const isVisible = (elem) => !!(
    elem.offsetWidth ||
    elem.offsetHeight ||
    elem.getClientRects().length
  )
  expect(isVisible(subject[0])).to.be.true
})
```

#### You can now chain it from contains

```
describe('Testing select options', function() {
  it('checks select option is visible', function() {

    const doc = cy.visit('http://localhost:4200')
    cy.get("mdc-select").contains("installation type").click()

    //cy.get('mdc-select-item').contains("ITEM1").should('be.visible') // this will fail
    cy.get('mdc-select-item').contains("ITEM1").isVisible()
  });
});
```

Comment: I get `Property 'isVisible' does not exist on type 'Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>'` error when I tried to use it. Somehow, command is not available.

Comment: Add it to your index.d.ts/js file too to be found by your IDE

Answer (score 3):

I could solve it by calling `scrollIntoView` after getting an element. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57833001).

Comment: This saved me 

Answer (score 2):

I came across this topic but was not able to run your example. So I tried a bit and my final solution is this. maybe someone other also needs this. Please note that I use typescript.

**First: Define a custom command**

```
Cypress.Commands.add("isVisible", { prevSubject: true}, (p1: string) => {
      cy.get(p1).should((jq: JQuery<HTMLElement>) => {
        if (!jq || jq.length === 0) {
            //assert.fail(); seems that we must not assetr.fail() otherwise cypress will exit immediately
            return;
        }

        const elem: HTMLElement = jq[0];
        const doc: HTMLElement = document.documentElement;
        const pageLeft: number = (window.pageXOffset || doc.scrollLeft) - (doc.clientLeft || 0);
        const pageTop: number = (window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop)  - (doc.clientTop || 0);
        let elementLeft: number;
        let elementTop: number;
        let elementHeight: number;
        let elementWidth: number;

        const length: number = elem.getClientRects().length;

        if (length > 0) {
            // TODO: select correct border box!!
            elementLeft = elem.getClientRects()[length - 1].left;
            elementTop = elem.getClientRects()[length - 1].top;
            elementWidth = elem.getClientRects()[length - 1].width;
            elementHeight = elem.getClientRects()[length - 1].height;
        }

        const val: boolean = !!( 
            elementHeight > 0 && 
            elementWidth > 0 && 
            elem.getClientRects().length > 0 &&
            elementLeft >= pageLeft &&
            elementLeft <= window.outerWidth &&
            elementTop >= pageTop &&
            elementTop <= window.outerHeight
        );

        assert.isTrue(val);
      });
});
```

Please note the TODO. In my case I was targeting a button which has two border boxes. The first with height and width 0. So i must select the second one. Please adjust this to your needs.

**Second: Use it**

```
cy.wrap("#some_id_or_other_locator").isVisible();
```

Answer (score 1):

A related problem: 
Cypress was unable to find a tab element because it had a style of display: none (even though it was visible on the page)

My workaround:
Cypress could target the tab by matching text and clicking

```
    cy.get("[data-cy=parent-element]").contains("target text").click();
```

Comment: but there would be still a style of display: none on the element, strange

Answer (score 0):

To expand a bit the answer of BTL, if anyone faced an error - `Property 'isVisible' does not exist on type 'Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>` in `Typescript`, following is what I added at the top of `commands.ts` in cypress to get away with it -

```
declare global {
    namespace Cypress {
        interface Chainable {
            isVisible;
        }
    }
}
```

And may be replacing `expect(isVisible(subject[0])).to.be.true` with `assert.True(isVisible(subject[0]));` if you see any chai assertion error with expect and don't want to import it - as in Josef Biehler answer..

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error that parent is hidden so Cypress is unable to click the child element, I handled this by handling the visibility of parent from hidden to visible by this code

```
cy.get('div.MuiDrawer-root.MuiDrawer-docked').invoke('css', 'overflow-x', 'visible').should('have.css', 'overflow-x', 'visible')
```

**Note: You can apply any css you want in the invoke function like I have**

Answer (score -1):

1. Remove the flex and try. If it is solved then use the flex standard way