# How to select value from drop down using cypress?

Tags: cypress

Here I am using cypress tool for automation. How to write code for dropdown menu

[image: drop down with search box and select button]

Here is the HTML code
[image: html code]

I just done like this way but its not working

```
cy.get('.dropdown-heading-dropdown-arrow').click()
cy.get('#0').click()
```

Comment: can you add the html code of your dropdown to the question. And also post the code that you tried?

Comment: @AlapanDas please check sir.....

Comment: Your html doesn't have the code for any of the dropdown values. can you add that?

Comment: @AlapanDas this dropdown  listing is  based on the previously created data for feature, if we create a new feature, then next page dropdown features shows- last created datas, we need to select from that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After dropdown opens search for the option with required text.

Not sure which selector might work for you, either `role` or `.MuiMenuItem-root` looks best, or try just getting any element with the text

```js
cy.get('.dropdown-heading-dropdown-arrow').click()

cy.contains('[role="option"]', 'Select All')      
  .click()

// or

cy.contains('.MuiMenuItem-root', 'Select All')      
  .click()

// or

cy.contains('Select All')
  .click()
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this. Gives a good explanation as well.

[select dropdownlist item using cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48362422/select-dropdownlist-item-using-cypress?rq=1)

Otherwise you can just get it by css selector, xpath or you can do `cy.contains`