# Selecting options from Mat-select using cypress

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, cypress

I have Mat-select dropdown as follows

```
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-label>Gender</mat-label>
      <mat-select id="gender" required formControlName="gender">
         <mat-option id="Male" value="male"> Male </mat-option>
         <mat-option value="female"> Female </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

I'm trying to use Cypress to select male or female from the field.

```
cy.get('mat-select').click().select('Male')
```

With the above code I get the following error:

```
CypressError: cy.select() can only be called on a <select>. Your subject is a: <mat-select>
```

I need some help in fixing this, thank you.

The code that worked for me.

```
cy.get('#gender').click().then(() => {
            cy.get('#male').click()
        })
```

Comment: Did you check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55897082/6663016)?

Answer (score 41):

Opens up the mat-option dialog for the mat-select & selects the field that contains "Apple Inc."

```
cy.get('mat-select[formControlName=companyName]').click().get('mat-option').contains('Apple Inc.').click();
```

Answer (score 9):

Basically what I did was to simulate the Dropdown opening and then sumulate another click for item selection:

```js
// simulate click event on the drop down
cy.get('mat-select').first()
        .click(); // opens the drop down

// simulate click event on the drop down item (mat-option)
cy.get('.mat-option-text span')
  .contains('Your MatItem Text')
  .then(option => {
            option[0].click();  // this is jquery click() not cypress click()
        });
```

Comment: Why are you using jQuery click and not Cypress?

Answer (score 4):

First, click on select for openning the overlay, then click on your option based on your option text content:

```js
cy.get('mat-select[formcontrolname="departament"]').click();
cy.get('mat-option').contains('Lima').click();
```

> My option text was ***Lima(+001)***. When I queried `.contains('Lima')` I got 'AssertionError'. But when I query `.contains('Lima')` or `.contains('001')` element is found. It's seems to me that only supports alphanumeric (I didn't go in deep).

Answer (score 2):

Just for other people still strugling with this/similar issue, even after trying the solutions presented here.

Your problem might also be that you are using a `within` block. Therefore `mat-select` items cannot be reached after clicking on the `mat-option`. So either take this part out of the `within` block or use the `{withinSubject:null}` option when getting the `mat-select` item.

```
cy.get("mat-select[formControlName*='language']").click();
cy.get('mat-option', {withinSubject:null}).contains('English').click();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work

```
cy.get('mat-select[formControlName=companyName]')
    .click()
    .then(() => cy.get('mat-option').contains('male').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 cy.get('div[class="cdk-overlay-container"]').then(($container) => {
    if ($container.find("div[class='cdk-overlay-connected-position-bounding-box']").length > 0) {
      cy.get("div[class='cdk-overlay-connected-position-bounding-box']").each(($el) => {
        $el.remove();
      });
    }
    if ($container.find("div[class^='cdk-overlay-backdrop']").length > 0) {
      cy.get("div[class^='cdk-overlay-backdrop']").each(($el) => {
        $el.remove();
      });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score -3):

First,Select for opening the overlay, then select your option based on your option text content & use `should()` to verify that selecting the exact option:

```js
cy.get('mat-select').select('Male').should('have.value','male');
```

Comment: not working for me  - message: 
can only be called on a <select>. Your subject is a: <mat-select...