# Element is not visible because it has CSS property: 'position: fixed' and its being covered by another element

Tags: cypress

Can someone help me with this Cypress error?

```
Cypress Error: Timed out retrying: expected '<div.sub-categories-list>' to be '0 visible'

This element '<div.sub-categories-list>' is not visible because it has CSS property: 'position: fixed' and its being covered by another element:

undefined
```

Comment: Can you share your code?, also is this happening  after page redirect/load?

Answer (score 15):

The element you are asserting is not visible within the viewport and probably have to be scrolled to in order to be visible.

Cypress do not automatically scroll to elements during the test run, but you can use `scrollIntoView()`, so write your assertion like this:

```
cy.get('#yourElement')
    .scrollIntoView()
    .should('be.visible')
```

Comment: It does not work because `scrollIntoView` does not scroll to the element. Focus stays on the view where it is. The (dirty) workaround `{ force: true }` helps. [My site](https://my-first-servless.netlify.app) to test with cypress.

Comment: scrollIntoView() is works for me.

Answer (score 3):

try to change css attribute/class of the element which is covering your desired element.

```js
cy.get("#coveringElement").invoke('addclass','hidden');
cy.get('#yourDesiredElement');
```

add the hidden class to all those which are covering your element.

Comment: This does not work, I cannot find in the cypress [docs for `invoke`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/invoke) the `addclass` prop.