# How does Cypress assert an element is visible when parent element has CSS property: display: none

Tags: javascript, css, cypress, display

How do I write a cypress visible assertion for an element whose parent has css property hidden?
I have the following HTMl code

```
<td class="item-total item-total-mobile-hidden">
<p class="mobile-show block-price-text">Total Price:</p>
<span class="price-total">
$699.99
</span>
</td>
```

When I write the following cypress code to assert that the price element is visible

```
Cy.get('.price-total').should('be.visible')
```

I get this error message
Timed out retrying: expected '<span.price-total>' to be 'visible'

This element <span.price-total> is not visible because its parent <div.item-total-price-mobile-show> has CSS property: display: none

I have to tried to debug this on the console (putting the span in a variable $0)

> $0
> <span class=​"price-total">​
> $699.99
> ​> ​
> Cypress.dom.isVisible($0)
> true

Here is shows the span element is isVisible true, but I am unable to assert it.
I tried the following by invoking the text on the child element, but it didn't work either

```
cy.get('.price-total').invoke('text')
      .then((text)=>{
        const divTxt = text;
expect(divTxt).to.be.visible; })
```

This did not work, I get the following error because cypress couln't find the hidden element
Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: .price-total, but never found it.

What's the best way to assert that the element <span class=​"price-total">​ is visible?

Comment: What version of Cypress are you using? There was a change to the way ‘be.visible’ works between 5.x and 6.x.

Answer (score 4):

You can retry while `.price-total` CSS has the `"display: none"` property like so:

```
cy.get('.price-total').should('not.have.css', 'display', 'none')
```

Comment: This would be a "double negative" validation of an element that is visible, I would prefer to have a straight forward validation of "is visible". But if nothing else works I would have to use it, I will probably add additional check that the element doesn't have "hidden" property

Comment: Found this page to be very useful also 
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/877

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I'm getting the complete picture, but good skills checking `Cypress.dom.isVisible($0)`.

You can use the exact same expression in your test by using `.should()` with a callback

```js
cy.get('.price-total')
  .should($priceEl => {     // retries if necessary when expect fails

    expect(Cypress.dom.isVisible($priceEl).to.eq(true)

  })
```

---

I'm not sure this is definitive, have seen an Angular app (select control) where the parent was `display: none` but the child was visible to the user (ref [Access element whose parent is hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47625195/14783414))

In this answer, a custom function is used to redefine the criteria for visibility. The trick is to figure out what to check for your app...

```js
// Change this function if other criteria are required.
const isVisible = (elem) => !!( 
  elem.offsetWidth ||                          
  elem.offsetHeight || 
  elem.getClientRects().length 
)
```

---

You may just have a delay (e.g animation) before the parent element removes `display: none`.

Check the parent in the console, see if it eventually has a different `display` value.

In that case, first check the **parent** (not the child as Manuel says).

```js
cy.get('td.item-total')
  .should('not.have.css', 'display', 'none')  
  .find('.price-total')
  .should($priceEl => {     
    expect(Cypress.dom.isVisible($priceEl).to.eq(true)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

If the parent of the element you are looking for has **display:none** then your element is not displayed(not visibled), to see that this is true just put:

`cy.get('.price-total').should('be.not.visible')`

**Note:** I am using cypress version: 8.3.1