# Cypress - Get [value] value property from mat-button-toggle-group

Tags: angular, angular-material, cypress

I have a selector to `<mat-button-toggle-group [value]="myValue"></mat-button-toggle-group>`

I want to have access to `[value]` value, and for that I do.

```js
buttonToggleGroupSelector.should('exist').and('has.value', 'MyValue');
```

But this returns an empty string and not the attribute value.

Comment: What does this return `buttonToggleGroupSelector` ?

Comment: @AlapanDas, thank you buttonToggleGroupSelector
      .should('exist')
      .and($el => expect($el)
        .to.equal('MyValue'));     - I Have tried like this and it returns <mat-button-toggle-group.mat-button-toggle-group.mat-button-toggle-group-appearance-standard> ,  i already try to do $el.attr('value') to and no success , if i add the attribute value without the [] cypress can get the value, but not with brakets, and whiteout the brakets i cannot make the bind.

Answer (score 7):

When you use

```js
buttonToggleGroupSelector.should('exist').and('has.value', 'MyValue');
```

Cypress is looking for a `value` property, but you want the `value` attribute

```js
buttonToggleGroupSelector.should('exist').and('has.attr', 'value', 'MyValue');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [invoke()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/invoke#Arguments-are-automatically-forwarded-to-the-function) method like so:

```js
buttonToggleGroupSelector.invoke('attr', '[value]').should('eq', 'MyValue')
```

Comment: You can also try without the the brackets around `'[value]'`.

Comment: Thank you, Manuel, yes, I have tried with the brackets and without the brakets, still return undefined :(

Comment: i notice if i declare <mat-button-toggle group value="myValue"> without the brackets, i can get the value, but if i have no brackets i cannot make the bind.

Comment: It's working then? You might have to play with it but it should work. I need to test in live environment tbh

Comment: i mapping an input variable to the [value] attribute in <mat-button-toggle-group [value]=Value that came in the input >, i think this value is undefined when the test starts. that is what is making sense to me.

Comment: Can you try adding some assertions `buttonToggleGroupSelector.shoud('exist').and('be.visible').invoke('attr', '[value]').should('eq', 'MyValue')`,

Comment: Hello Manuel, now i get -- is not visible because its content is being clipped by one of its parent elements, which has a CSS property of overflow: hidden, scroll or auto

Comment: I think this answer will solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66647365/9884190

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `buttonToggleGroupSelector` returns something like `cy.get('mat-button-toggle-group')`, then you can do:

```js
buttonToggleGroupSelector.should('have.attr', '[value]', 'myValue')
```

Comment: it still returns undefined, but i notice if i declare <mat-button-toggle group value="myValue"> without the brackets, i can get the value, but if i have no brackets i cannot make the bind.