# How to get child element from parent element having multiple same items?

Tags: get, css-selectors, location, cypress, parent-child

I am stuck at child element location. The attributes of child elements are having multiple items, also attributes of parent element are multiple items. I am finding difficulty in locating child element. Element action click() is not working.

Html:

```
<div class="locale-selector" xpath="1">
<span class="locale-selector-heading"> Your location and language</span>
<div class="locale-selector-country-wrapper" data-metrics-section="Site_lvl1_LocLangSelector">
   <a href="#" class="locale-selector-country" aria-controls="localization-container" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
       <div class="locale-selector-flag-heading-wrapper">
           <span class="flag-header-global flag-hong-kong"></span>
           <span class="locale-selector-country-heading">Hong Kong</span>
       </div>
       <span class="locale-selector-chevron-arrow"></span>
   </a>
</div>
</div>
```

span tag having multiple classes,div tag having multiple same classes.

How can I perform click() action on class ?

```
class="locale-selector-country-heading"
```

My attempt:

```
cy.get('.locale-selector-country-heading').contains('Hong Kong').click()
```

Error:

`<span class="locale-selector-country-heading">Hong Kong</span>`

This element `<span.locale-selector-country-heading>` is not visible because its parent `<div.locale-selector-flag-heading-wrapper>` has CSS property: `visibility: hidden`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access element whose parent is hidden - cypress.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47551639/access-element-whose-parent-is-hidden-cypress-io)

Comment: {force:true} worked for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is telling you that a parent element is making the whole section of the DOM tree not actionable.

You can force the click, to turn off actionability checks

```js
cy.get('.locale-selector-country-heading').contains('Hong Kong').click({force:true})
```

but then your test is somewhat not realistic - the user can't click something that's not visible.

However, sometimes the actionability checks are incorrect - if you can actually see the element, go ahead and use `{force:true}`.

Otherwise, the element may be transitioning into a visible state (via CSS animation).

In this case, you want to add a retry on the visibility with `.should('be.visible')`

```js
cy.get('.locale-selector-country-heading').contains('Hong Kong')
  .should('be.visible')
  .click()
```

There's a section on actionability here [Interacting with Elements](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/interacting-with-elements)

Comment: thank you. This resolved my issue using {force:true} as I can see the element . If I go for should('be.visible') , it is showing same error.